# How do I keep a panel from being forced under two other panels when the window is made smaller?

Tags: asp.net, css

I have three panels like so:

```
 ___    _________    ___
|   |  |         |  |   |
|   |  |         |  |   |
|   |  |         |  |   |
|   |  |         |  |   |
|___|  |_________|  |___|
```

But if I shorten the window a little bit, the middle panel goes below the two side panels:

```
 ___                ___
|   |              |   |
|   |              |   |
|   |              |   |
|   |              |   |
|___|              |___|
 _________ 
|         |
|         |
|         |
|         |
|_________|
```

Here is my code

```
<style>
   .SidePanel {
       background-color:#9999CC;
       width:100px;
       height:597px;
   }
</style>

<div style="text-align:center;">
         <div style="float:left">
             <asp:Panel ID="Panel4" runat="server" CssClass="SidePanel" BorderColor="DarkBlue" BorderWidth="2px"/>
         </div>

         <div style="float:right">
                    <asp:Panel ID="Panel5" runat="server" CssClass="SidePanel" BorderColor="DarkBlue" BorderWidth="2px"/> 
         </div>

         <div style="display:inline;">
             <asp:Panel ID="Panel0" runat="server" BackColor="#9999CC" BorderColor="DarkBlue" BorderWidth="2px" Width="900">
                 ...content...
             </asp:Panel> 

            </div>
</div>
```

How would I stop it from doing this?

EDIT: Here are the changes I made from responses.

```
<style>
  .SidePanel {
      background-color:#9999CC;
      height:597px;
  }
</style>

<div style="text-align:center; min-width:1024px; width:100%;">
            <div style="float:left; width:10%">
                <asp:Panel ID="Panel4" runat="server" CssClass="SidePanel" BorderColor="DarkBlue" BorderWidth="2px"/>
            </div>

            <div style="float:right; width:10%">
                <asp:Panel ID="Panel5" runat="server" CssClass="SidePanel" BorderColor="DarkBlue" BorderWidth="2px"/> 
            </div>

            <div style="width:70%">
                <asp:Panel ID="Panel0" runat="server" BackColor="#9999CC" BorderColor="DarkBlue" BorderWidth="2px" style="width:100%;">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try putting a wrapper around it with a min-width.  There's got to be a better way to handle this situation though.  Can you show the complete layout?  A link to a live page or a layout diagram?

Comment: Also, what is the point of the "display: inline;" in the content <div>?

Comment: @Mark, left over from when I was trying to get the layout to work. The wrapper with min width worked, but there isn't a live page because the site is only on the company intranet. One thing that happens now though, is when the content is squeezed, the middle panel grows larger and the others don't. Is there a way to make the side panels grow with the middle panel?

Comment: Up at the bottom of the original post

Comment: Are you testing it IE?  I believe IE <7 treats min-width as a fixed width.

Comment: IE8 because thats all our users will be using.

Comment: No worries then. (IE6 is the one to worry about in that case).  Can you show the doctype you are using?  If it's not there or incomplete it will trigger quirks mode and cause issues with the layout.

Comment: To center the div I'd surely leave out the display:inline; and use margin:auto; instead.

Comment: I don't have the display inline anymore. And here is my doctype:
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: Add the margin: auto; to center the content div then: <div style="width: 70%; margin: auto;">

Comment: Make sure to test the layout and see if you can break it by adding/subtracting content, increasing text size (if it survives 3 I'm usually happy) and anything else you can think to throw at it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Three Little Panels, All in a Row</title>
<style>
#container
{
min-width:800px;
overflow:auto;
}
.littlePanels
{
float:left;
width:100px;
background-color:#999900;
}
.bigOlePanel
{
float:left;
width:600px;
background-color:#CC9966
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
<div class="littlePanels">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="bigOlePanel">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="littlePanels">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this works!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that middle panel was squeezed. To be sure add wrapping div with explicit width (say 1000), and all another assign also explicit width. Take in mind you have 2px border - so subtract 4 total from each one.

And at last - instead of 'inline' of middle div, review possibility to assign it 'float=left' also.

Comment: Then it isn't centered. But I removed the display:inline, and it works the same way

Comment: @Justen, display:inline doesn't cause "squeezing" middle div down - the problem is (a) unmatched width (b) questionable flowing of blocks. My recommendation about flow - just make your code more clear.